# I am getting this error "UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENT" in docusign API

Tags: docusignapi

My docusign API code was working very fine and i didn't change anything in my code, so now when i am sending document to the users then it's not working and getting "UNABLE_TO_CONVERT_DOCUMENT" error.

Can you please let me know why this error is coming and what should i do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

DocuSign converts every document into a pdf in the backend. When you send a document to DocuSign, the system has to first "flatten" it which means remove anything that is not pure visual (like macros etc.) and make a visual copy (the pdf). That can fail for a number of reasons. First, it's possible you don't have a valid representation of a document (like an empty doc or invalid doc). Second, it's possible the document is password protected. DocuSign cannot use third party resources either. If to see the document your system has to make API calls to other systems (like SharePoint etc.) then DocuSign will fail to convert this document. Try a simple text file with a few characters to start with and see if that works first. Also, you can try to upload the same document that failed directly to DocuSign website to eliminate issues in your code as well.